# How to execute this SQL commands in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

i am trying to execute commands for the DB from a WinForm project, when i run this command on phpmyadmin everything works, but i don't know how to run it from my project. Can someone help me?

```
set @autoid :=0;
update Products set id = @autoid := (@autoid + 1);
alter table Products Auto_Increment = 1;
```

Comment: I assume this is a MySQL database? Are you using ODBC, OLE-DB, or MySQL's own client library?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Yes it's MySQL, db client version: libmysql - mysqlnd. (From "https://www.freesqldatabase.com/")

Answer (score 0):

It seems MySQL from referring phpmyadmin

You can use `MySql.Data` to execute query which you can install this module from Nuget.

In your case you can use:

```
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
 
var connectionString = "server=localhost;user=userid;database=yourdb;password=yourpassword";
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
 
try
{
    connection.Open();
 
    var sql = "set @autoid :=0; update Products set id = @autoid := (@autoid + 1);alter table Products Auto_Increment = 1; ";
    var mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
}
 
connection.Close();
```

Comment: This probably needs `Allow User Variables = true` in the connection string. https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#AllowUserVariables